# How to destroy a has_many :through association by selected user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have groups of users. A user creates a group and is the owner. They can accept/deny requests(which works fine), create groups(also works), and I want them to be able to delete group members(which isn't working). For some reason, the owner of the group is all that is able to be deleted from the group.

How do I set up the controller action/view to let the owner delete group members?

P.S. I do not want to use an authorization system for this. It should be simple enough to do just in the controller. I just need to be able to delete any group member. **Groups = Cliqs.** I did not make memberships a nested resource of groups.

**The error**: Couldn't find CliqMembership with 'id'=2 [WHERE `cliq_memberships`.`user_id` = ?]

Here is my controller action:

```
def destroy
  @cliq = Cliq.find_by(params[:cliq_id])
  @cliq_membership = @cliq.cliq_memberships.find(params[:id])

  @cliq_membership.destroy
  redirect_to cliqs_path
end
```

My models:

```
class Cliq < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'

  has_many :cliq_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :members, through: :cliq_memberships, source: :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :owned_cliq, foreign_key: 'owner_id', class_name: 'Cliq', dependent: :destroy

  has_many :cliq_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cliqs, through: :cliq_memberships
end
```

My View controller action:

```
def show
  @cliq = Cliq.find(params[:id])
  @cliq_owner = @cliq.owner
  @cliq_members = @cliq.members
  @pending_members = @cliq.pending_members
  @cliq_requests = @cliq.cliq_requests #(find a way to show all incoming requests)
  @cliq_memberships = CliqMembership.all
end
```

And my "actual" view:

```
<div>
  <% @cliq.members.each do |member| %>
    <ul><%= link_to member.username, user_path(member) %></ul>
  <% end %>
  <% @cliq.cliq_memberships.each do |cliq_membership| %>
    (<%= link_to "Delete Member", cliq_membership, :method => :delete %>)
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Log:

```
Cliq Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `cliqs`.* FROM `cliqs` LIMIT 1
CliqMembership Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `cliq_memberships`.* FROM `cliq_memberships` WHERE `cliq_memberships`.`cliq_id` = 4 AND `cliq_memberships`.`id` = 9 LIMIT 1
Completed 404 Not Found in 18ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find CliqMembership with 'id'=9 [WHERE `cliq_memberships`.`cliq_id` = ?]):
app/controllers/cliq_memberships_controller.rb:44:in `destroy'
```

Comment: When it fails, is there an error logged anywhere? What's the message? If you are not sure, try changing `destroy` to `destroy!`

Comment: I'll update the question to include the error message.

Comment: Thanks, would you also please add the bit from your `log/development.log` file that covers the DELETE request.

Comment: I added the log file for the request. I also edited my question to reflect the change that I made that seems to be partially work. It only allows me to delete the first created Cliq(because of the way the find_by method works), but will not allow me to delete the "selected" Cliq's membership association. I've tried find_by_id and find_by(id: params[:cliq_id]), but to no avail. How do I fix this?

Comment: Just solved it. Check answer.

Answer (score 0):

try change `has_many :cliq_memberships, dependent: :destroy` to `has_many :cliq_memberships, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: 'member_id'`

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now, but I'll try that. Would I need to specify class_name or :source?

Comment: You would have to check you schema table tho. I am suspecting that in your cliq_memberships table, the foreign id you used is `member_id` instead of `user_id`, that's why you get the error message

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by checking my request code(which is also a has_many :through association and has similar actions). Not sure why I took so long to solve it.

I changed my method to this:

```
def destroy
    @cliq = Cliq.find_by(params[:cliq_id])
    @cliq_membership = CliqMembership.find(params[:id])

    @cliq_membership.destroy
       flash[:notice] = "You left the Cliq."
    redirect_to cliqs_path
end
```